# passing parameters to ajaxminfy

Tags: vbscript, ajaxmin

I have this below script that I use to call the ajaxminy exe using a vbscript ..I am getting an error saying expected '(' .Can someone please look at it and tell me what's wrong.stroutput1 and outputpath are variables that I want to pass in to the script.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\AjaxMin.exe"" stroutput1 -o outputpath)
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Complete"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is wrong. `Run` expects a command string (enclosed in double quotes), and double quotes inside this string must be doubled to escape them. Change this:

```
objShell.Run(""C:\Prog...fier\AjaxMin.exe"" stroutput1 -o outputpath)
```

into this:

```
objShell.Run """C:\Prog...fier\AjaxMin.exe"" stroutput1 -o outputpath"
```

and perhaps append `, 0, True` (run hidden and wait for the command to return).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There should've been only 2 double quotes after `AjaxMin.exe`. Fixed.